# Sql query with string not like condition

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an sql Query

```
Select Itemcode from StocktransferlocationDetails 
where Projectname='" +  projectname_stockout + "'  and 
       Stocktransferlocation !='" + location_stockout + "' and Status='Open'
```

which not working correct when used in C# but it worked in SQl correctly i used the following query in sql

```
  Select Itemcode from StocktransferlocationDetails 
  where Projectname='iupl'  and Stocktransferlocation !='Chennai-Bangalore' 
        and Status='Open'
```

how to do this

Comment: side-note: always use [`parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to prevent sql-injection and avoid conversion issues.

Comment: And your exception or unexpected (and expected) result would be...?

Comment: !! Do not use string manipulation to build SQL on the client. You are leaving yourself wide open for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!!

Comment: What error your getting or what result your getting from both(SQl and C#)

Comment: use <> for not equal to in sql

Comment: @Arshad: Even if <> is ANSI compliant != works also in T-SQL, so that's not the reason of his issue.

Comment: When you create you sql string in C# want does that string say prior to execution?  Can you post that here?  If you take that string and execute it directly does it work?

Comment: my expectations is it have to show the Itemcodes which are not having Stocktransferlocation as"Chennai-Bangalore". Table have other values as "Bangalore-Delhi". but it didnt show any results.It show empty result

Comment: when i remove Stocktransferlocation from condition it shows the result

Answer (score 1):

it has to be a quoted string and you should instead use SqlParameter to prevent Sql Injection.

```
var sql = "Select Itemcode 
              from StocktransferlocationDetails 
              where Projectname = @ProjectName  
              and Stocktransferlocation <> @Stocktransferlocation 
              and Status='Open'";

var param1 = new SqlParameter("@ProjectName", projectname_stockout);
var param2 = new SqlParameter("@Stocktransferlocation", location_stockout);
```

This is only part of the solution and you should use a SqlCommand object to populate the query with parameters.

Comment: Query used in is as follows                                                                         SqlCommand cmd_totalopen = new SqlCommand("Select Itemcode from StocktransferlocationDetails where Projectname='" + projectname_stockout + "'  and  Stocktransferlocation NOT LIKE '" + location_stockout + "' and Status='Open' ", st.con);

Comment: It also not working. Shows result as empty

Comment: You need to elaborate what's not working? What error / exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

In C# you should use like this :-

```
string query="Select Itemcode from StocktransferlocationDetails"+ 
+" where Projectname=" +  projectname_stockout + "  and "+
      +" Stocktransferlocation !=" + location_stockout + " and Status='open'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what query is send to the SQL Server.

1. From code (your querystring).
2. Use SQL Server Profiler (open from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio > tools > SQL Server Profiler).

There must be something different with the query from code and the one in management studio.